# Creating a full-screen option from WPF tab controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I have inherited a comprehensive WPF (C#) application that makes extensive use of tabs and other WPF controls. How do I go about creating a full-screen option for some of these tabs? I have used WPF extensively before but I'm trying to maximize the amount of code re-use for this part of my application.

This application is often show using a notebook connected to a projector on a 6'x6' screen. So any help with optimizing the WPF controls for this type of set-up would be appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing an example its tough to see what your needs are exactly. But have you tried MyWindow.WindowState=Maximized?

Comment: Really? Because the second line clearly states, "How do I go about creating a full-screen option for some of these tabs? "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open it in a new window with `WindowStyle` set to `None` and `ResizeMode` set to `NoResize` this will make it full screen... You could use a `DataTemplate` for your tab header that will display full screen button and another button on the full screen window to close it and return to the app...

Comment: This sounds along the right track. How would i make this work with controls that are within a tab? Keep in mind that I want to re-use the existing controls at some point.

Comment: Within the Grid element that is there by default when you create the new Window you can put single content element like this <ContentControl Content="{Binding TabContent}"/> and when you instantiate the Window pass in the reference to the UserControl displayed in the tab and make that your windows content...

Answer (score 0):

Does the full-screen window need to be interactive? If you just want to display the content there, you could paint the background with a [VisualBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx). On a full-screen window, define the background as:

```
<Window.Background>
    <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding Path=SelectedContent}" />
</Window.Background>
```

Set the DataContext of this window to your TabControl, and the selected tab content will be copied to it and stretched to the full window size.

Comment: Yes, I do need the screen to remain interactive.

Comment: @JimBeam To be clear, the VisualBrush isn't a static image. It's a real-time clone of the source visual. So you could be editing on the laptop screen while it's duplicated and resized on the projector.